# SVELTE calling await function when value returned by function changes on template

Tags: svelte

I don't understand why SVELTE is calling the function specified in an {#await} block when the values returned by the function are changed.

I've made a little example:

https://svelte.dev/repl/a962314974eb4a07bd98ecb1c9ccb66c?version=3.35.0

In brief:

```js
{#await getList() then alist}
    {#each alist as item}
    <div>
        {item.state}
        <div class="button" on:click={()=>item.state=!item.state}>Toggle it!</div>
    </div>
    {/each}
{/await}
```

Function `getList()` is called every time I click on "button" div to toggle a value on object returned by the function. I don't understand why.

Somebody could enlighten me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because the whole component is rerendered when the state is changed, and as such `getList()` is called again as it's in the render code.

A better solution might be to find how to avoid the whole rerender with [immutable](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/svelte-options), but here's a way to make this work:

```
<script>
    let list = [
        { state: true}, { state: true}, { state: true},{ state: true}
    ]
    let counter = 0;
    async function getList(){
        counter++;
        return Promise.resolve(list);
    }
    const promise = getList()
</script>

Times GetList called: {counter}

{#await promise then alist}
    {#each alist as item}
    <div>
        {item.state}
        <div class="button" on:click={()=>item.state=!item.state}>Toggle it!</div>
    </div>
    {/each}
{/await}
```

Comment: Thank you! I fixed mine waiting for the promise on the <script> part, but yours sticks more to the original and is more beautiful.

Comment: I'll dig on the 'immutable' as well, I saw it in the docs, but I didn't understand exactly the meaning. Now I see better.

Answer (score 0):

A state change does not (normally) cause the entire component to rerender, this is the base tenet of Svelte after all.  You can try this by adding a second counter and a button inside the await:

```html
{#await getList() then alist}
  <button on:click={() => counter2++}>Clicked {counter2}</button>
  ...
```

Clicking this button will increase *counter2* without firing `getList` again.

The issue here seems to be caused by the fact that you are editing the result of the async operation directly, which somehow retriggers said operation. Considering the other answer works this must have something to do with it being a function call.

An alternative approach to fix this would be to move the internals of your each loop into it's own component:

```html
{#await getList() then alist}
  {#each alist as item}
    <Child {...item} />
  {/each}
{/await}
```